# How much 'charge energy' does Transform give when used by a Ditto?

Tags: pokemon-go

Let's say Ditto uses Transform, then it copies the opponent's moveset and gains some energy. How much energy does the Ditto gain per 1 Transform?

Most Charge moves cost some energy, with the exception of Struggle, which costs 0 energy.

Without energy, it is impossible to use Charge Moves with bars. Struggle is a Charge Move without any bars.

Comment: What do you mean by "energy"? HP, stamina or charge for charge moves?

Comment: They're asking how much energy it charges as in the energy used to perform a charge attack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to energy for charge moves, Transform gives 0 energy.